# how to make usort work

Tags: php, arrays, usort

```
$string = 'aaaaa,val1,1111; ddddd,val2,2222; gggg,val3,3333;';

$string = rtrim($string, ";");

$one = explode(';', $string);

$array = array();

$i = 0;

foreach($one as $o)
{
    $two = explode(',', $o);

    $name = $two[0];
    $value = $two[1];
    $price = $two[2];

    $array[$i]['name'] = $name;
    $array[$i]['value'] = $value;
    $array[$i]['price'] = $price;

    $i++;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);

usort($array, 'sort_by_order');

function sort_by_order ($a, $b)
{
    return $a['price'] - $b['price'];
}

print_r($array);
```

If you copy my codes above you can see the display right away.
I am trying to make my `usort()` work. Sort based on price. I follow a tutorial on `usort()` I do not understand how it works. How does the $a and $b comes into play?

Comment: So what's the problem? working:-https://eval.in/665353

Comment: @Anant After usort the price with the highest value should be in key 0 right?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys but I had made it work in descending order

```
return $b['price'] - $a['price'];
```